# How to order random hierarchy data which I have in list

Tags: grails, hierarchy

Actually I am working data analysis kind of project where i am dealing with hierarchy data.

I have a list within list of hierarchy data like below

```
dataList = [[Id:1, Manager id:0, String:s], [Id:4, Manager id:0, String:p], [Id:7, Manager id:0, String:s],[Id:8, Manager id:1, String:s], [Id:2, Manager id:1, String:s],
[Id:3, Manager id:2, String:s],[Id:9, Manager id:8, String:s],[Id:5, Manager id:4, String:s]]
```

> **Id** is id and **Manager id** is parent id    `//Manager id with 0 dont have any parent`

So, Is it possible to order data list according to **hierarchy**. Before I was using **dojoTreeTable** or **dojo** but its taking so much amount of time when dealing with 10k records because need to add extra variable to order according to hierarchy.

[image]

Please dont take care of view much I have already did it already. But this for **expand all** which i am implementing now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort them first by "Manager id" and next by "Id".  Then reduce them to a map from "Manager Id" to a list of children:

```
def p = "P"
def s = "S"
def dataList = [[Id:1, 'Manager id':0, String:s], [Id:4, 'Manager id':0, String:p], [Id:7, 'Manager id':0, String:s],[Id:8, 'Manager id':1, String:s], [Id:2, 'Manager id':1, String:s], [Id:3, 'Manager id':2, String:s],[Id:9, 'Manager id':8, String:s],[Id:5, 'Manager id':4, String:s]]

def sortByManagerIdAndId = { a,b ->
    a."Manager id" <=> b."Manager id" ?: a.Id <=> b.Id
}

def hier = dataList.sort(sortByManagerIdAndId).inject([:].withDefault{[]}) { m,e ->
    m[e."Manager id"] << e; m
}

assert hier.keySet() == dataList*."Manager id".toSet()
assert hier[0]*.Id == [1,4,7]
assert hier[4]*.Id == [5]
```

From there build your UI model (or do so directly in the reduce step)

Comment: so you want to transform you list of maps into hierarchy/tree?  what should data structure of that tree look like?  what have you tried?

Comment: Sorry you didn't understood question. your result **dataList** is in normal order and i am  looking for hierarchy order. order shown in above **Screenshot**. If i have hierarchy order then i can easily iterate list and can display. if i don't have sorted ad hierarchy order then it will not display as in above image.

Comment: Above **Screenshot** is exact tree structure but i did it for expand on one node click. but i am looking for **expand all** at a time

Comment: I am not getting any logic to order in hierarchy order so i haven't tried anything till.